# htaccess url parameter get value with index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
`example.com/recent/index.php?page=2`  i want to like this -> `example.com/recent/page/2`
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /recent/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

index.php?page=2

```
<?php
echo $_GET['page'];
?>
```

how to create for that htaccess file. how to it from last url `example.com/recent/page/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /recent/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: if u can plz help me this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002755/getting-value-and-redirect-with-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite urls using .htaccess files. But before writing something in .htaccess files we need to verify which kind of server we are using. Here in the case you may use either an apache server or a Nginx server. You can easily check by just adding a

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

in a php page.

**Case 1 : Apache Server:**

Ensure that mod_rewrite module enabled in apache server. This can be identified by checking phpinfo included page.

Common methods used for url rewriting is as follows

**RewriteEngine**

This is mandatory for any apache server. This is used to enable the rewriting engine. In some cases it should be on by default.So ensure that following code must be mandatory in top of your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
```

**RewriteRule**

in some cases you may have only few pages and you can specify each page in your website in .htaccess file. In such case you can use these kind of rewriting 
For example

RewriteRule ^article/used/to/be/here.php$ /article/now/lives/here/ [R=301,L]

Suppose you have to rewrite url like these

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/url_rewriting
```

You should write something like these on your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^wiki/(.+)$   w/index.php?title=$1   [L]
```

But actual implementation of the page will be like these

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=url_rewriting

**RewriteCond**

This can be used for rewriting certain url with respect to some conditions. Suppose you need to add or remove www with your website name and on certain condition redirect to certain page like "url not available or error message "

Example :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
```

You can further refer here

[Introduction to url rewriting](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/)

[Rewrite with examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples-2/)

**Case 2 : nginx Server**

Enable module HttpRewriteModule on your nginx server
Use location to rewrite you urls as per nginx settings

Example

```
    location / {
    root   /path/to/drupal;
    index  index.php index.html;
 
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
 
location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}
```

Comment: i dont know how fix it. from thi link how to get last number `http://www.col3negmovie.com/recent/page/2` this pagenation.

Comment: and i want to display this page col3negmovie.com/recent/index.php

Comment: if u can plz help me for this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002755/getting-value-and-redirect-with-htaccess