# Getting Value and redirect with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want redirect `http://example.com/search/search.php?q=videos` to  `http://example.com/search/videos`

I tried to do it but its not work. here my htaccess file: `http://example.com/search/.htaccess`

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /search/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ load.php?q=$1 [L]
```

last `RewriteRule` is not work.. how to fix it.. help for that.. thanks `RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ load.php?q=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in `/search/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /search/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: cant use in search folder?

Comment: If you want in search folder then let me change the code

Comment: not redirect this one :( example.com/search/search.php?q=videos

Comment: You need to enter: `http://example.com/search/videos` in browser not the `search.php` URL.

Comment: no i want to this link example.com/search/search.php?q=videos  redirect to example.com/search/videos  like this..

Comment: amazing friend... :) thanks lot of.. respect you. :) acctually thanks.

Comment: if u can plz help me this post also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025518/removing-trailing-slash-for-sub-directory-url-indexing

Comment: if u can plz help me for this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172422/getting-value-with-htaccess-and-pagination

Comment: if u can plzz help me for this post also.. plzz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058593/getting-value-with-symbol-from-htaccess