# Getting value with htaccess and pagination

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This url

```
example.com/videos/load.php?cat=video-category
```

would become

```
example.com/videos/video-category
```

---

Also, there is pagination url

```
example.com/videos/load.php?cat=video-category&p=2
```

and it would become

```
example.com/videos/video-category/page/2
```

---

I tried to do this.. but it doesn't work.
Here is my htaccess (into `videos` folder)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /videos/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+/+/)page/?$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)(?:/[^/]+)?/?$ load.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your htaccess.
This should work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /videos/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ load.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/?$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page/([1-9][0-9]*)$ load.php?cat=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: example.com/videos/video-category/ this link not work :(

Comment: I edited my answer and added the possibility to have `video-category` and `video-category/`. But you should allow only one of them to avoid duplicate content

Comment: yeah. but i can redirect from php

Comment: plzz if u can help for this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381679/htaccess-change-a-path-to-a-query-strings