# Getting value with symbol from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This url

```
example.com/ad/load.php?id=pay.jpg
```

would become

```
example.com/ad/pay.jpg
```

I tried to do this.. but it doesn't work.
Here is my htaccess (into `ad` folder)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ad/

RewriteRule ^(\w+) ./load.php?id=$1
```

Edit

on this root `example.com/ad/` I want to show index.php but it does not show. how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regex should allow dot also. Try this in `/ad/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ad/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ load.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: With the `.` now matching, load.php would recurse. Just exclude it and it's all good then.

Comment: Thanks so much @RaviThapliyal, I overlooked it initially, fixed now.